# How to write unit test for a function that takes a call back as its argument?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, callback

How to write a unit test for a function that takes a callback function as parameter?

```
unsigned __int32 
MyStream::DoThis(callBackFunction in_Function, 
                 unsigned __int32 in_Length)
{
    //some code
    //some code
    return readStream->DoThis(in_Function, dataLength);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a stub callback function which raises flag inside its body.
2. Invoke your UT and pass the stub as an argument to your function.
3. After execution finish assert that the flag was raised.